# Microcontroller - potential damage to IO pin

Tags: microcontroller, protection

I'm revisiting a design I made.

The circuit is powered by 24V with polarity protection.

I placed a power loss detection before the polarity protection:

[image]

In case the power pins were replaced, the 3v3 zener diode will have forward voltage of ~1V.

will this pin go through R32 to the "unpowered microcontroller" and destroy its IO pin?

The absolute maximum is -0.3V in the mcu:

[image]

It's only 100uA limited by R32, but I can't be sure.

Is there such detailed information about the IO pin?

Comment: I don't think I understand your text. You write that there will be "~1V", which is well within -0.3 to +4.0 V. Do you mean -1V? In that case, do you mean to also draw -23 V over the resistors, and reverse the current direction through R32?

Comment: What is the documented impedance on that pin? The pin (and diode) make a voltage divider with R32.

Comment: Also, you want the fuse before the TVS devices, so that a constant overvoltage blows the fuse before the TVSes.

Comment: @pipe yes its -1v but in if you see it from cathode to anode .. yes it goes through R32 to microcontroller io pin .. the pin it self will have clamping diode  .. thats why 100uA limited ..^^

Comment: @JonWatte im not sure i follow up .. there is somthing ~50ohm in the pins to reduce EMI ringing .. the diode will clamp that 1v to 0.3 i think ..

Comment: @JonWatte for the fuse its PTC .. 
maybe i need wire type fuse before the TVS and MOV ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the datasheets, in the absmax section, give an information like "-0.3 V or -10 mA, whichever occurs first", but unfortunately not in this case; therefore a proper answer is not possible, but I can give a bit of insight.

The -0.3V limit is there because for each pin there is a diode from ground to the pin, and from the pin to vdd. With 10 kOhm in series, this is a non issue; I would expect almost any IC to be able to handle at least a few mA in the protection diodes, and here you have a 10 kOhm resistor in series. You can even bump the resistor up to 100 kOhm, if I understand your circuit correctly.

To sum it up, with your series resistor you are not violating the absmax because the diode will conduct and block the voltage around -0.3 V, probably even less. With 100 uA you can sleep safe.

Comment: That's an under-specified aspect of many data sheets.  IMHO, it would be more helpful if they were to say something like "The device will tolerate without side-effects beyond power dissipation whatever amount of current flows through the clamp diode at VDD+0.3V, and will likewise tolerate whatever voltage it would reach if 10mA or less is fed into the pin" but some devices may have side effects even when current levels wouldn't damage the device.  For example, on one 74HCxx part I used, if an input was driven with 1mA above the rail and the adjacent input was grounded, that 1mA would flow...

Comment: ...out through the adjacent input (which for the circuit in question caused trouble since that input was passively pulled down with a 4.7K resistor).

Comment: Great question and answer also fully agree with @supercat - lazy data sheets are far too common

Comment: Yeah I guess they put in what they manage to simulate/test... And for what they do not put in, all bets are off.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Unfortunately, the way most data sheets are written, it would be possible to design any kind of practical device that doesn't rely upon things that aren't specified.  For example, if one has two chips running off the same power rail, feeding an output from the chip which is closer to a 5.000V supply to one which is slightly further way, could cause an out-of-spec condition if the first chip manages to output 4.999V, but the distance to the supply causes the voltage reaching the second to drop to 4.998V.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Of course, in practice no logic-level chip is going to malfunction as a consequence of an input which exceeds its supply rail by 1mV, but if one wanted to design a circuit that was guaranteed by data sheet specifications to operate correctly, one would need to add a couple resistors to reduce the voltage fed to the second chip's input to ensure that it would always be strictly less than that chip's supply voltage.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: I suspect part of the issue is that data sheet designers don't want to block the possibility of improving performance with future die revs, but practical circuits sometimes need guarantees that would impose limits on performance, such as guaranteed minimum propagation delays.  Personally, I wish that there had been a convention of specifying four thresholds for clock inputs: the data input must be valid one set-up time before the clock reaches the first threshold and must remain valid for a hold time after it reaches the second.  The output is guaranteed...

Comment: ...not to change until the clock reaches the third threshold, and is guaranteed to switch within a propagation time of the input reaching the fourth.  Once the clock reaches any threshold, it must cross the next before re-crossing the previous, but jitter around any single threshold will have no effect.  Given such specs, slew-rate-limited clock signals could guarantee setup/hold compatibility among any combination of logic speed families if the worst-case second and third thresholds were adequately far apart.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: For example, if a transmitting device's minimum propagation time could be as short as 0ns and the receiving device's hold time could be as long as 10ns, ensuring reliable operation would merely require limiting the clock signal's slew rate so that it would spend 10ns between the second threshold of the receiver and the third threshold of the sender.

Comment: The internal input protection diodes in a microcontroller normally conduct at around 0.7V. So for a safety margin the input spec is Vdd + 0.3V and Vss - 0.3V. If external protection diodes are added to the micro inputs then these should be schottky diodes which conduct at around 0.3V thereby ensuring that the internal 0.7V diodes don't conduct.

Comment: Microchip have an appnote for AVR devices where they use the ESD diodes to allow direct connection to the mains through a resistor. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-2508-Zero-Cross-Detector_ApplicationNote_AVR182.pdf You're safe. For sure.

Comment: Further, the ATSAM4D datasheet specifies 1mA is acceptable on page 877, section 37.10 but unfortunately, the ATSAM4E has no such section...

Answer (score 3):

According to the datasheet this is indeed a violation of the absolute maximum rating, with the caveat that the current not being specified. It might be okay, but not guaranteed.

I would look into a small power monitor IC which can detect when the input voltage is about to get low and signal your MCU. These are available at a wide variety of ‘trigger’ voltages and can be simpler/cheaper than doing your own comparator circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the voltage detection to after the polarity protection mosfet and your MCU won't see the negative voltage.

Also, for detecting voltage, use a resistor divider circuit that gives you 2.5V or whatever  your threshold is at 15V in (so, 56 kOhm to 10 kOhm or so, or even 560k to 100k to save power). Then parallel the zener with the lower leg for protection; far under 3.3V it won't conduct a lot and won't impact your UV detection significantly.

Comment: there are big fat caps there .. i want to detect power failure and write on memory .. thats why i put it before the pmos ..

Answer (score 0):

Insert (add) a diode after R32 
for any sensing of voltages this is a standard protection
This offer reverse protection to input pins however any I /O pins will have two diodes one to the Vcc in forward bias to take care inputs exceeding the Vcc
Other to Gnd to take care of reverse voltages occurring on in put pi

Answer (score 0):

As others have said the current limiting R32 means it will all be ok, but you could move the UVLO tap to the right of the FET and then it would definitely be better.  But ...

In your schematic you have a comment about the UVLO circuit being wrong and needing a comparator.

Take a look at shunt regulators such as the tlv431.  These three pin devices can be used as comparator with integrated reference and driven straight from pretty much any supply with only a series resistor provided you can protect against reverse polarity.

Answer (score 0):

That will definitely overcurrent the cpu pin.

I just use a schottky diode right on the v+ input to prevent against reverse polarity. FSV10100v might work depending on your current requirements.

You can then spin off a small separate circuit if the supply is reversed to turn on some user indication (led?).

Comment: hi @emBee .. there is already polarity protection PMOS .. i didnt want to add another one .. the power loss detection i wanted it before the PMOS as i want to detect the uvlo before the circuit uses the charges in the capacitors ..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for injection current in the data sheet.  Also fix the divider,  set it so the zener doesn't conduct under normal circumstances.  Failing this ask their web site.  But I agree keep the current into the micro to less than 1-2 mA is usually good enough.  An alternative is to use a bas99 as clamp diodes.  There was a paper done a long time ago about their use as esd protection.  The other part of this is to remember what you are protecting.. micro pin so after the 10k series resistor.  Use the 10k as a buffer. Or split the 10k in 2

Comment: this wasn't divider but the zener was working in knee point thats why the current is 5mA .. (16v min - 3.3 / 2200ohm = 5mA) .. any less value than 14v will start making the zener to work below the knee point